# How to set Template property of a ContentControl in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, contentcontrol

I have a ContentControl is defined in XAML like this:

```
<ContentControl Width="100"
    Height="100"
    Canvas.Top="100"
    Canvas.Left="100"
    Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
    <Ellipse IsHitTestVisible="False" Fill="Blue"/>
</ContentControl>
```

And I want to create another one by code but I don't know how to set the Template property. Anyone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Test.Template=Application.Current.FindResource("DesignerItemTemplate")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the Template in some ressources (App, Window, Grid, whatever, ...)

```xaml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate"  TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

2. In code behind, find the resource and assign the Template :

```c#
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    contentControl1.Template = Resources["DesignerItemTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
}
```

Regards

Comment: @khunglongxanh, did you give a try to my answer ?

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel DURIN but I find it so hard to do in this way. I found another solution. :)

Comment: Actually, it 's Nothing different that the answer to your question ... I am surprised you find it hard